# Vertically centering button text that has more inherent space below it than above it

Tags: css

My button, defined as `<a href='#' class='button'>Click</a>` and styled as `.button { background: red; padding: 20px; }`, isn't vertically centered because the font I'm using has more inherent space below it than above it. Is there a way to center it without changing the markup, and if not what's the best option?

EDIT: using `line-height` instead of padding works for default font, not with the one I'm using.

[image]

(the gray around the button is my page background not a border)

Comment: set line-height equal to height of the box

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height`. This sets the height of the text and provides an invisible, equal padding vertically. Note, this trick will only work on block elements. So if you want to use it on an `a` tag, you will need to convert it to a block element (using `display: block`)

```css
a.button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width:100px;

  /* The magical lines */
  line-height: 3em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">Text</a>
```

This is ideal for single-line text in an element--not so much for multiline elements.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the font I'm using. If I use a default font it works though.

Comment: In that particular case, you may need to add some `padding-top` to adjust it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height property instead of padding for vertical center alignment

Comment: Thanks, doesn't work with the font I'm using though.

Comment: @drake035 could you edit code to include the font that you are using and any other css that is being applied to the element here?